# Magento 2 - How to get class file from event name observer on stripe payment module

Tags: magento2, event-observer, payment, class, stripe

I got this event observer code in the stripe payment module

```
<event name="payment_method_assign_data_stripecreditcards">
        <observer name="stripecreditcards_payment_gateway_data_assign" instance="Stripeofficial\CreditCards\Observer\DataAssignObserver" />
    </event>
```

I looking for dispatch event for `payment_method_assign_data_stripecreditcards` but I'm not found it on the `vendor` folder, my goals is get know when and from what class file that make this event name triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find event in this file

```
vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/AbstractMethod.php
```

and function name is `assignData()`

```
  public function assignData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data) {
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'payment_method_assign_data_' . $this->getCode(),
        [
            AbstractDataAssignObserver::METHOD_CODE => $this,
            AbstractDataAssignObserver::MODEL_CODE => $this->getInfoInstance(),
            AbstractDataAssignObserver::DATA_CODE => $data,
        ]
    );

    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'payment_method_assign_data',
        [
            AbstractDataAssignObserver::METHOD_CODE => $this,
            AbstractDataAssignObserver::MODEL_CODE => $this->getInfoInstance(),
            AbstractDataAssignObserver::DATA_CODE => $data,
        ]
    );

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: ah i see so the dispatch event name use dynamic value on the edge of string variable.. that why I cannot find it everywhere when search by full event name.  thank you very much

Comment: you most welcome

Comment: Accept answer if its helps you

Comment: need waiting 3 minutes to accept the answer :p